# How to layout tables and relationships for MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I am working on an MVC project to put to work the studying I have been doing.  I am wrestling with the concept of Database Table relationships and foreign keys.  I am working on a simple ecommerce site (displays products, shopping cart, user accounts..etc).

I have the following tables to start out with:

1) Products
2) Categories

I setup the Products and Categories tables to have a ProductId and CategoryId respectively.  In my MySQL db, I created a FK on the Products Table to relate to the CategoryId field on the Categories table (I am not sure this was correct to begin).

My expectations for the way the database would handle the table relationship:  I didn't want the DB to do anything with the products table if I deleted a category out of the Categories table, or vise versa.  The only thing would be that the category field in a Product would be blank (or default) if their category was removed.

Finally, do I have to do anything in my entity classes such as in the Products class, add the ProductId to the Category.ProductId?

Eventually, when I Orders and Users to the project, I can see a relationship where each user -> many orders -> each order has many products -> and each product is in one category.

But I am having a hard time understanding how or if I should be setting up a Foreign key relationship in the two current tables of Products and Categories and if so how to setup my entity class in relation to that FK.

Any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience (with L2S) that you don't want to specify any relationships between tables. I have simply done the PK, FK logic myself. This keeps the L2S generated objects simple and is most likely the way you worked with them before in SQL. That, at least, is the case for me.